# Tensorflow on IBM Power9 ppc64le - Can libtensorflow.so be deleted?

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, conda, powerpc

I tried to build a docker container with python and the tensorflow-gpu package for a ppc64le machine. I installed miniconda3 in the docker container and used the IBM repository to install all the necessary packages. To my surprise the resulting docker container was twice as big (7GB) as its amd64 counterpart (3.8GB).

I think the reason is, that the packages from the IBM repository are bloating the installation. I did some research and found two files `libtensorflow.so` and `libtensorflow_cc.so` in the `tensorflow_core` directory. Both of theses files are about 900MB in size and they are not installed in the amd64 container.

It seems these two files are the API-files for programming with C and C++. So my question is: If I am planning on only using python in this container, can I just delete these two files or do they serve another purpose in the ppc64le installation of tensorflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Those are added as there were many requests for it and it's a pain to cobble together the libraries and headers yourself for an already built TF .whl.

They can be removed if you'd rather have the disk space.

What is the content of your "amd64 container"? Just a pip install tensorflow?

Comment: Thank you very much! I build both container images with the same docker file leveraging the $TARGETARCH environment variable. So both of them install the needed packages with conda. See: https://gist.github.com/flxh/2f0a9f4fba043773719bc344b61895c6